# New SAP Instance not working. No instance profiles found

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, vmware, sap-basis

I have installed sap server 7.51 on ubuntu virtual machine (vmware). Installation was successful but when I run start I get the following error:

> ```
> ubuntu:npladm 1> startsap all
> No instance profiles found
> please send the tracefile /home/npladm/startsap.trc to support
> ```

I typed ifconfig and got the following:

> ```
> ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 192.168.234.130  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.234.255
>         inet6 fe80::e152:4277:1c5f:3311  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>         ether 00:0c:29:9f:48:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>         RX packets 1739  bytes 1139138 (1.1 MB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 1406  bytes 145716 (145.7 KB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
>         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
>         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>         RX packets 5009  bytes 1102113 (1.1 MB)
>         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>         TX packets 5009  bytes 1102113 (1.1 MB)
>         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```

I checked that the ip address in the host file is correct as in:

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

# mapping the Ubuntu loopback IP 127.0.1.1 to ubuntu
192.168.234.130 ubuntu  ubuntu.dummy.nodomain

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback fe00::0 ip6-localnet ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

# mapping the Ubuntu loopback IP 127.0.1.1 to vhcalnplci
127.0.1.1   vhcalnplci  vhcalnplci.dummy.nodomain
```

As you can see the ip adress should be correct (192.168.234.130) and is pingable but it is still not working.

**Update:**

Here is also the trace log file:

```
Trace of system startup/check of SAP System NPL on Mon Jul  1 01:08:45 PDT 2019


{01:08:45 ## Main() start: @=/usr/sap/NPL/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64/startsap all
 @(#) $Id: //bas/749_STACK/src/krn/startscripts/startsap#1 $
 BASENAME=startsap

 {01:08:45 ## check_user() start: @=npladm
 }01:08:45 ## check_user() done

 #=1
 @=all

 {01:08:45 ## setPlatform() start
  PLATFORM=linuxx86_64
 }01:08:45 ## setPlatform() done

 {01:08:45 ## setPing() start
  PING=/bin/ping
 }01:08:45 ## setPing() done

 {01:08:45 ## setIfconfig() start
  IFCONFIG=/sbin/ifconfig
 }01:08:45 ## setIfconfig() done

 {01:08:45 ## setIp() start
  IP=/sbin/ip
 }01:08:45 ## setIp() done

 {01:08:45 ## setRootDir() start: @=
  USR_SAP=/usr/sap
  USR_SAP_SID=/usr/sap/NPL
  PROFILE_DIR=/usr/sap/NPL/SYS/profile
  DIR_LIBRARY=/usr/sap/NPL/SYS/exe/run
 }01:08:45 ## setRootDir() done

 {01:08:45 ## setDbUser() start: @=
 }01:08:45 ## setDbUser() done

 Argument=all

 {01:08:45 ## getarg() start

  {01:08:45 ## checkInstance() start: @=all
  }01:08:45 ## checkInstance() done: 1

  {01:08:45 ## checkTask() start: @=all
   _opt=all
  }01:08:45 ## checkTask() done: 0

  TASK=ALL
 }01:08:45 ## getarg() done: 1

 {01:08:45 ## setVHostArray() start
  _PROFILES=/usr/sap/NPL/SYS/profile/NPL_ASCS01_ubuntu /usr/sap/NPL/SYS/profile/NPL_D00_ubuntu
  _nrProfiles=2

  {01:08:45 ## pushVHostsFromProfile() start: @=/usr/sap/NPL/SYS/profile/NPL_ASCS01_ubuntu /usr/sap/NPL/SYS/profile/NPL_D00_ubuntu
   _DUMMY=NPL_ASCS01_ubuntu
   _VHOST=ubuntu

   {01:08:45 ## isVHostLocal() start: ubuntu
    VHOST=ubuntu
    _IS_LOCAL=0
   }01:08:46 ## isVHostLocal() done: 0

   _DUMMY=NPL_D00_ubuntu
   _VHOST=ubuntu

   {01:08:46 ## isVHostLocal() start: ubuntu
    VHOST=ubuntu
    _IS_LOCAL=0
   }01:08:46 ## isVHostLocal() done: 0

   VHOSTS=
  }01:08:46 ## pushVHostsFromProfile() done

  VHOSTS=
 }01:08:46 ## setVHostArray() done

 {01:08:46 ## set_instance() start
  NINST=
  INSTFOUND=0
  NINSTFOUND=0
  hasABAP=0
  hasJava=0
  hasSpecial=0
 }01:08:46 ## set_instance() done

No instance profiles found

Exit code 8
```

Any other ideas about the error and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

updating the ip-address of my VM in /etc/hosts helped:

```
> sudo nano /etc/hosts
..
192.168.1.218   vhcalnplci vhcalnplci.dummy.nodomain
```

.. then i started server

```
> startsap ALL
```

.. and checked that instances are running

```
> sapcontrol -nr 00 -function GetProcessList
```